# Systemd Service does not stop Before=suspend.target

Tags: systemd, services, suspend

I am having troubles executing a systemd service just **before** state `suspend.target` but it does not work. Instead the `systemd` service seems to execute **after** `suspend.target` no matter what I do. I tried a variety of things however I don't know what to look for anymore.

This is what I currently have:

- The "main" service file, running a python script:

  `python_service.service`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Python Systemd Service

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/python_service.py --user "user" --password "password"
  Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
  Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
  Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
  Restart=on-failure
  RestartSec=5
  User=root

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Now to stop and restart this service I decided to create 2 other systemd service files with the only purpose to execute `systemctl stop python_service.service` and `systemctl restart python_service.service` like this:

  `python_service_stop.service`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Stop python_service before suspend
  Before=suspend.target

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/bin/systemctl stop python_service.service
  User=root

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

And no matter what I try it **always** stops this service **after** the PC resumes despite defining `Before=suspend.target`.

Now the question is: How can I make it so `python_service.service` does actually stop **before** reaching `suspend.target`?